# Accessing Watson Studio Lite, cannot create resource group

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Hi I'm currently trying to deploy Watson Studio Lite but it will not allow me to do this without a resource group. And when I'm trying to create a resource group I do not have permission to do so.

Could someone please advise? IM taking the IBM data science certification online with Coursea and their instructions are either dated or not specific to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

when creating a new IBM Cloud account, a default resource group *should* be created automatically. Unfortunately you will not be able to create another one without upgrading to a paid account. There are two options:

1. You can chat with support in the [support center](https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/cases/form).
2. You can create a new account with a different email address.